# How to get the IOS and Android crash logs for the specific application using python

Tags: python, android, ios, crash-reports, headspin

I'm trying to build a tool and It will check the crash logs for the specific application in the real device which is running in the cloud environment (Headspin). Is there any way to achieve this? I don't have any reference to proceed for initial code.

Can someone guid me the direction and let me know is this operation is possible or not?